# I have a Variation of Calculus, Euler Lagrange, Lagrange Multiplier problem and I don't know how to continue.

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation

So I can't continue with my work. Don't know if I am just not seeing something under my nose or something.

Given formula:
$$I=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}[(x'_2)^2-(x_2)^2]dt$$

with auxiliary constraints and initial conditions:
$$x'_1+x'_2-x'_3=0;        x'_1+2x'_3=0$$

$$x_1(0)=0;  x_2(0)=0; x_3(0)=0$$
$$x_1(\pi/2)=-\pi; x_2(\pi/2)=3\pi/2; x_3(\pi/2)=\pi/2$$

From here I calculated the Lagrange Equations using the Formula:

$$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x'_i})-\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_i}
+\sum_{\mu=1}^p (\lambda_\mu [\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial G_\mu}{\partial x'_i})-\frac{\partial G_\mu}{\partial x_i}]+\frac{\partial G_\mu}{\partial x'_i}\frac{d\lambda_\mu}{dt})$$

With $G_1$ and $G_2$ representing the 2 auxiliary constraints and $\lambda$ representing the Lagrange Multipliers, of which there are 2.

The Above Equation was given to me in my textbook.
Said Lagrange Equations are:
$$\frac{d}{dt}[\lambda_1+\lambda_2]=0$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}[2x'_2-2x_2+\lambda_1]=0$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}[2\lambda_2-\lambda_1]=0$$

From the first and third equation one can see that $\lambda$ is constant because $\lambda'_1=\lambda'_2=0$

From the second equation it stands that
$$2x'_2-2x_2+\lambda_1=d$$

where $d$ is a integration constant.

This is where I am stuck.

Comment: Where are $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,G_\mu$ from?

Comment: $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the lagrange multipliers.
$G$ are the auxiliary constraints